# Cloudera 4 - Hdfs / Hbase - Internal communication over second NIC in private network

Tags: hbase, hdfs, cloudera, nic

we have set up CDH4 (hdfs, hbase, hue, mapreduce, oozie and zookeeper) on a test cluster using the Cloudera Manager. Everything works fine except we can not seem to figure out how to make the nodes communicate via eth1 in a private network while still accessing the manager via eth0 from outside.
Any suggestions on where to configure that?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by manager I assume you are referring to the HBase master. You should know that clients that connect to HBase connect to regionservers (they connect to ZooKeeper quorom, which in turn points them at a regionserver).

You can get the cluster to use an one NIC over the other with `hbase.master.dns.interface`, `hbase.regionserver.dns.interface` and `hbase.zookeeper.dns.interface` settings in the hbase-default.xml ([see config files in HBase Book](http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html))

However, as noted above that will not solve your problem. I guess you can use the REST or ThriftServer as an external API and then have that access HBase over the internal network